# Spring batch ItemReader locale, import a double with comma

Tags: spring-batch

I want to import the following file with Spring Batch

```
key;value
A;9,5
```

I model it with the bean

```groovy
class CsvModel
{
    String key
    Double value
}
```

The shown code here is Groovy but the language is irrelevant for the problem.

```groovy
@Bean
@StepScope
FlatFileItemReader<CsvModel> reader2()
{
    // set the locale for the tokenizer, but this doesn't solve the problem
    def locale = Locale.getDefault()
    def fieldSetFactory = new DefaultFieldSetFactory()
    fieldSetFactory.setNumberFormat(NumberFormat.getInstance(locale))

    def tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(';')
    tokenizer.setNames([ 'key', 'value' ].toArray() as String[])

    // and assign the fieldSetFactory to the tokenizer
    tokenizer.setFieldSetFactory(fieldSetFactory)

    def fieldMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<CsvModel>()
    fieldMapper.setTargetType(CsvModel.class)

    def lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<CsvModel>()
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer)
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldMapper)

    def reader = new FlatFileItemReader<CsvModel>()
    reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource('output/export.csv'))
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1)
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper)

    return reader
}
```

Setting up a reader is well known, what was new for me was the first code block, setting up a numberFormat / locale / fieldSetFactory and assign it to the tokenizer. However this doesn't work, I still receive the exception

```
Field error in object 'target' on field 'value': rejected value [5,0]; codes [typeMismatch.target.value,typeMismatch.value,typeMismatch.float,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.value,value]; arguments []; default message [value]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'float' for property 'value'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9,5"]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.java:200) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:180) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
```

So the question is: how do I import floats in the locale de_AT (we write our decimals with a comma like this: 3,141592)? I could avoid this problem with a `FieldSetMapper` but I want to understand what's going on here and want to avoid the unnecessary mapper class.

And even the `FieldSetMapper` solution doesn't obey locales out of the box, I have to read a string and convert it myself in a double:

```groovy
class PnwExportFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<CsvModel>
{
    private nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())

    @Override
    CsvModel mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException
    {
        def model = new CsvModel()
        model.key = fieldSet.readString(0)
        model.value = nf.parse(fieldSet.readString(1)).doubleValue()
        return model
    }
}
```

The class `DefaultFieldSet` has a function `setNumberFormat`, but when and where do I call this function?

Answer (score 4):

This unfortunately seems to be a bug. I have the same Problem and debugged into the code.

The BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper is *not* using the methods of DefaultFieldSetFactory, that would do the right conversion, but instead just uses FieldSet.getProperties and does the conversion by itself.

So, I see the following options: Provide the BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper either with PropertyEditors or a ConversionService, or use a different mapper.

Here is a sketch of a conversion Service:

```
private static class CS implements ConversionService {

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class<?> sourceType, Class<?> targetType) {
        return sourceType == String.class && targetType == double.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        return sourceType.equals(TypeDescriptor.valueOf(String.class)) &&
               targetType.equals(TypeDescriptor.valueOf(double.class)) ;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T convert(Object source, Class<T> targetType) {
        return (T)Double.valueOf(source.toString().replace(',', '.'));
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        return Double.valueOf(source.toString().replace(',', '.'));
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
      final BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<IBISRecord> mapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        mapper.setTargetType(YourClass.class);
        mapper.setConversionService(new CS());

...
new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<IBISRecord>()
.name("YourReader")
                .delimited()
                .delimiter(";")
                .includedFields(fields)
                .names(names)
                .fieldSetMapper(mapper)
                .saveState(false)
                .resource(resource)
                .build();
```